# Node js Php Cookies

Tags: php, node.js, cookies

i want to set cookie on login for example:

```
         cookie('id' , '554');
```

then i want to access this cookie from nodejs server ???

i am using socket.io to listen to to this nodejs server

without any requests or any thing ??

i am trying to use cookie-parser but i have to to get cookies from request

problem is there no requests just socketio listen to nodejs server

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are saved in Client Side of the communication. Without a message from the client (Aka: Request, or in sockets' case, a message), you won't be able to access the cookies' data.

NOTE: A socket's message doesn't transmit the cookies' data automatically. You'll have to send them within the message.